# Issue viewing Aggregations and Activity Search - BAM portal

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-bam

I am working on BAM (first encounter), created a simple Activity where I have defined two Business Milestone (Invoice received and Invoice processed time) and one Business Data (Customer Name) and a simple view complementing it with Dimensions "Customer (customer name) " and Date(Invoice processed time) and Total Amount as a value.

Deployed the Activity and View followed by deployment of tracking profile .

I cross verified with the BAMPrimaryDatabase and tables are created, also I get results back when I query on them.

Now the issue is that I don't get it reflected on BAM portal. And when I click on Aggregations a pop up with following errors appears:

> Views cannot be displayed for one or more of the following reasons:
>
> - Office Web Components 2003 are not installed. (I have installed it)
> - Your Web Browser does not support ActiveX controls.
> - Support for ActiveX controls is disabled.(Have enabled the ActiveX controls)

When I click OK , following shows up on the portal:

> Provider=MSOLAP; Data Source=MAHESH-PC;Initial Catalog=BAMAnalysis[InvoiceView_InvoiceTotalAmount]Customer[InvoiceView_InvoiceTotalAmount_Customer].[InvoiceView_InvoiceTotalAmount_Customer].[Customer]Column1[Customer]Year[InvoiceView_InvoiceTotalAmount_Date].[InvoiceView_InvoiceTotalAmount_Date].[Year]Row1[Date]Total Amount[Measures].[Total Amount][Measures].[Total Amount]DataRow-1Total AmountData1[Measures].[Total Amount]InvoiceTotalAmount
>   Pivot Table View 
>   Chart View

Is it generic (known issue) or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying cube needs to be built in BAMAnalysis. After you complete that step you can view your data. The next question you might have is, how often this needs to be built?